# Problem writing to all fragments programmatically as viewpager is loading

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an viewpager/adapter with four fragments. This is working fine and I can write to editText Views in each fragment individually.

My problem is that when I try to write saved data to editTexts programmatically as the adapter is loading, Android writes to only one fragment.

In theory I should be able to write to each one during the onResume() method, but it's just not happening.

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button Button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_activity);

    Button = findViewById(R.id.btGo);

    Button.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void onClick(View v) {

    gotoEngine();
}

public void gotoEngine() {


    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent homeSheet = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, ViewPager2.class);

            startActivity(homeSheet);
        }
    });

}
```

}

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {

static int counter = 0;

static EditText ET;

public myFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static myFragment newInstance() {

    myFragment currentPage = new myFragment();

    return currentPage;

}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View myTextViewFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment, container, false);

    ET = myTextViewFragment.findViewById(R.id.editText);

    return myTextViewFragment;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}


@Override
public void onResume() {

/////////// This Method is called once for each fragment but it will not populate all editText Views


    super.onResume();

    counter++;

    if (counter == 1) {

        ET.setText("First Fragment");
    }


    if (counter == 2) {

        ET.setText("Second Fragment");
    }


    if (counter == 3) {

        ET.setText("Third Fragment");
    }


    if (counter == 4) {

        ET.setText("Fourth Fragment");

        counter = 0;
    }


}
```

}

```
public class ViewPager2 extends FragmentActivity {

static android.support.v4.view.ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager2);

    viewPager = findViewById(pager);

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); //This sets the number of fragments to keep alive while swipping.

    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            populateTextView(arg0);

        }


        public void populateTextView(int arg0) {

            ////////// Here, only the last Fragment's editText is set....

            if (arg0 == 0) {

                myFragment.ET.setText("Zero");

            }

            if (arg0 == 1) {

                myFragment.ET.setText("One");

            }

            if (arg0 == 2) {

                myFragment.ET.setText("Two");


            }

            if (arg0 == 3) {

                myFragment.ET.setText("Three");

            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub - The next statement works

        }


        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (arg0 == android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                ////// Tried Setting the editText here, but didn't work.
            }

            if (arg0 == android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {


            }

            if (arg0 == android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {

            }

        }
    });


    PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = findViewById(R.id.pager_tab_strip);

    pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);

    pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.YELLOW);

}


class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        if (arg0 == 0) {

            return myFragment.newInstance();
        }


        if (arg0 == 1) {

            return myFragment.newInstance();
        }


        if (arg0 == 2) {

            return myFragment.newInstance();
        }


        if (arg0 == 3) {

            return myFragment.newInstance();
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        // ( return the number of 'pages' )

        return 4;
    }


    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                return "Page Zero";

            case 1:
                return "Page One";

            case 2:
                return "Page Two";

            case 3:
                return "Page Three";
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out, the key to this issue is the onViewCreated Method on the fragment, this will allow you to populate each fragment individually:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // add your code here which executes after the execution of onCreateView() method.

    counter++;

    if (counter == 1) {

        TV.setText("One");

    }


    if (counter == 2) {

        TV.setText("Two");

    }


    if (counter == 3) {

        TV.setText("Three");

    }


    if (counter == 4) {

        TV.setText("Four");

        counter = 0;

    }


}
```